# Templates not rendered in Airflow unit test

Tags: python, unit-testing, airflow

I have a Python module which is structured as follows:

```
my_module/
  ...
  tests/
    __init__.py
    my_test.py
    ...
```

where `my_test.py` is defined as follows:

```
from __future__ import print_function, unicode_literals

import os
import unittest
from datetime import timedelta, date

from airflow import configuration
from airflow.models import TaskInstance as TI, DAG, DagRun
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.settings import Session
from airflow.utils import timezone
from airflow.utils.state import State

DEFAULT_DATE = timezone.datetime(2016, 1, 1)
END_DATE = timezone.datetime(2016, 1, 2)
INTERVAL = timedelta(hours=12)
FROZEN_NOW = timezone.datetime(2016, 1, 2, 12, 1, 1)

TI_CONTEXT_ENV_VARS = ['AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_ID',
                       'AIRFLOW_CTX_TASK_ID',
                       'AIRFLOW_CTX_EXECUTION_DATE',
                       'AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID']


class Call:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs


def build_recording_function(calls_collection):
    """
    We can not use a Mock instance as a PythonOperator callable function or some tests fail with a
    TypeError: Object of type Mock is not JSON serializable
    Then using this custom function recording custom Call objects for further testing
    (replacing Mock.assert_called_with assertion method)
    """
    def recording_function(*args, **kwargs):
        calls_collection.append(Call(*args, **kwargs))
    return recording_function


class PythonOperatorTest(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super(PythonOperatorTest, cls).setUpClass()

        session = Session()

        session.query(DagRun).delete()
        session.query(TI).delete()
        session.commit()
        session.close()

    def setUp(self):
        super(PythonOperatorTest, self).setUp()
        configuration.load_test_config()
        self.dag = DAG(
            'test_dag',
            default_args={
                'owner': 'airflow',
                'start_date': DEFAULT_DATE},
            schedule_interval=INTERVAL)
        self.addCleanup(self.dag.clear)
        self.clear_run()
        self.addCleanup(self.clear_run)

    def tearDown(self):
        super(PythonOperatorTest, self).tearDown()

        session = Session()

        session.query(DagRun).delete()
        session.query(TI).delete()
        print(len(session.query(DagRun).all()))
        session.commit()
        session.close()

        for var in TI_CONTEXT_ENV_VARS:
            if var in os.environ:
                del os.environ[var]

    def do_run(self):
        self.run = True

    def clear_run(self):
        self.run = False

    def is_run(self):
        return self.run

    def _assertCallsEqual(self, first, second):
        self.assertIsInstance(first, Call)
        self.assertIsInstance(second, Call)
        self.assertTupleEqual(first.args, second.args)
        self.assertDictEqual(first.kwargs, second.kwargs)

    def test_python_callable_arguments_are_templatized(self):
        """Test PythonOperator op_args are templatized"""
        recorded_calls = []

        task = PythonOperator(
            task_id='python_operator',
            # a Mock instance cannot be used as a callable function or test fails with a
            # TypeError: Object of type Mock is not JSON serializable
            python_callable=(build_recording_function(recorded_calls)),
            op_args=[
                4,
                date(2019, 1, 1),
                "dag {{dag.dag_id}} ran on {{ds}}."
            ],
            dag=self.dag)

        self.dag.create_dagrun(
            run_id='manual__' + DEFAULT_DATE.isoformat(),
            execution_date=DEFAULT_DATE,
            start_date=DEFAULT_DATE,
            state=State.RUNNING
        )
        task.run(start_date=DEFAULT_DATE, end_date=DEFAULT_DATE)

        self.assertEqual(1, len(recorded_calls))
        self._assertCallsEqual(
            recorded_calls[0],
            Call(4,
                 date(2019, 1, 1),
                 "dag {} ran on {}.".format(self.dag.dag_id, DEFAULT_DATE.date().isoformat()))
        )
```

In a terminal, when I run `nosetests test/my_test.py`, the test fails because the Jinja templates are not correctly rendered. The full log is given below.

```
======================================================================
FAIL: Test PythonOperator op_args are templatized
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/my_module/tests/my_test.py", line 120, in test_python_callable_arguments_are_templatized
    "dag {} ran on {}.".format(self.dag.dag_id, DEFAULT_DATE.date().isoformat()))
  File "/home/user/my_module/tests/my_test.py", line 88, in _assertCallsEqual
    self.assertTupleEqual(first.args, second.args)
AssertionError: Tuples differ: (4, datetime.date(2019, 1, 1), 'dag {{dag.dag_id}} ran on {{ds}}.') != (4, datetime.date(2019, 1, 1), 'dag test_dag ran on 2016-01-01.')

First differing element 2:
'dag {{dag.dag_id}} ran on {{ds}}.'
'dag test_dag ran on 2016-01-01.'

- (4, datetime.date(2019, 1, 1), 'dag {{dag.dag_id}} ran on {{ds}}.')
?                                     ^^   ---------        ^^^^^^

+ (4, datetime.date(2019, 1, 1), 'dag test_dag ran on 2016-01-01.')
?                                     ^^^^^           ^^^^^^^^^^

-------------------- >> begin captured logging << --------------------
airflow.utils.log.logging_mixin.LoggingMixin: INFO: Reading the config from /home/user/airflow/airflow.cfg
airflow.settings: INFO: Configured default timezone <Timezone [UTC]>
airflow.logging_config: DEBUG: Unable to load custom logging, using default config instead
--------------------- >> end captured logging << ---------------------
```

However, there is nothing wrong with the code in `my_test.py` since it is only a subset of the file [test_python_operator.py](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/tests/operators/test_python_operator.py) file from [Airflow github repository](https://github.com/apache/airflow) (`v1-10-stable` branch). Naively, I would expect this test to run just fine but it does not.

> What am I missing ?

**EDIT**: I'm using apache-airflow 1.10.2, Python 3.6.8 and nose 1.3.7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because, the fields `'op_args'`, `'op_kwargs'` were not templatized fields in **Airflow 1.10.2** for `PythonOperator`. The link you have in your question is of the master branch of Airflow repository.

`'op_args'`, `'op_kwargs'` were added after Airflow 1.10.2 was released.

Commit that included those fields to `template_fields` (this is still in master and not included in any release version): https://github.com/apache/airflow/commit/7ab245b296efc73db3ce4ce0edbae473e357698c

For Airflow 1.10.2: check this file - https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.10.2/tests/operators/test_python_operator.py

Also, do not use `v1-10-stable` branch as it contains the code for the upcoming release **1.10.3**. You should use the **1.10.2** tag instead: https://github.com/apache/airflow/tree/1.10.2

**PythonOperator** (1.10.2):
https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.10.2/airflow/operators/python_operator.py#L65

```
class PythonOperator(BaseOperator):
    template_fields = ('templates_dict',)
    template_ext = tuple()
    ui_color = '#ffefeb'

    @apply_defaults
    def __init__(
            self,
            python_callable,
            op_args=None,
            op_kwargs=None,
            provide_context=False,
            templates_dict=None,
            templates_exts=None,
            *args, **kwargs):
...
```

**PythonOperator** (master - development branch):
https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/operators/python_operator.py#L72

```
class PythonOperator(BaseOperator):
    template_fields = ('templates_dict', 'op_args', 'op_kwargs')
    ui_color = '#ffefeb'

    # since we won't mutate the arguments, we should just do the shallow copy
    # there are some cases we can't deepcopy the objects(e.g protobuf).
    shallow_copy_attrs = ('python_callable', 'op_kwargs',)

    @apply_defaults
    def __init__(
        self,
        python_callable,  # type: Callable
        op_args=None,  # type: Optional[Iterable]
        op_kwargs=None,  # type: Optional[Dict]
        provide_context=False,  # type: bool
        templates_dict=None,  # type: Optional[Dict]
        templates_exts=None,  # type: Optional[Iterable[str]]
        *args,
        **kwargs
    ):
```

Answer (score 0):

You most probably use `1.10` or earlier versions to run tests. In that versions `op_args` in `PythonOperator` **was not** templated. But in `master`, which you most probably are using tests from, `op_args` **are** templated, and are tested accordingly. If you really want to use airflows test as an example you should grab them from whatever branch that correspond's to your installed version.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I edited my post. I'm using apache-airflow 1.10.2 and the code for the test file is from the v1-10-stable branch. I think that the problem is somewhere...

Comment: the  [change](https://github.com/apache/airflow/commit/c74f6c337b25c53a4a4da7951ee2b3a0b3eeb96a) was merged to `v1-10-stable` on 27th of March. I believe it is not part of `1.10.2`. You can look at the code of your local `PythonOperator` and see whether you have:

```template_fields = ('templates_dict', 'op_args', 'op_kwargs')
```